# How can I display any file inside a web browser?

Tags: php, file, yii, flexpaper

I am making a web site where the site needs to keep the user files. My problem: I have a list of files `( docs, pdf, img, xml, excel )`. I need to show the user each file's contents when they click a file from the list. I know how to work with `img`, but other file types I don't. I tried with [flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/default.jsp), but it supports only `pdf`.
My question is : **Do you know any way to display any type of file or a library that supports all (or at least more) file types?**

If it is important, I use in server side `php`(exectly `yii` ). Again one thing is important, the files need to be in my server.

Comment: One possible option is to generate jpeg previews of documents on the server side. Otherwise, users must have respective browser plugins (office etc) installed.

Comment: Have you considered Google Docs? May be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doc viewer is support `( docs, pdf, excel )` files, other files e.g. `image`, `xml` browser native support,

For instance google doc viewer

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

[**Google Doc viewer**](https://docs.google.com/viewer)